# Why are three extra zeros added in the datetime.time milliseconds field?

Tags: python, datetime, milliseconds

I'm parsing through a log file and saving different values in different variable. When I insert milliseconds in `datetime.time(hour,minute,second,millisecond)` it adds three extra zeros in front of the millisecond value, why?

```py
lst = ['13', '33', '30.913']
hour = int(time[0], 10)
minute = int(time[1], 10)
second = int((time[2].split('.'))[0], 10)
millisecond = int((time[2].split('.'))[1], 10)
print(millisecond)
time = datetime.time(hour, minute, second, millisecond)
print(time)
```

I expect `13:33:30:913` from `print(time)`, but the actual output is `13:33:30:000913`

However the output from `print(millisecond)` is `913`, which is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4th argument to [`datetime.time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time) is actually microsecond and not millisecond:

> datetime.time(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, **microsecond=0**, tzinfo=None, *, fold=0)

In order to make your code work you should multiply your millisecond by 1000 and printing can be done using the [`isoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.isoformat) method:

```
time = datetime.time(hour, minute, second, millisecond * 1000)
print(time.isoformat('milliseconds'))
```